# Volume of a solid - setting the boundaries

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

We have to calculate the volume of a solid in the first octant, bounded by $$z=4-x^2-y$$.

I have calculated the following boundaries:
All lower boundaries 0.
Upper boundary for $$z = 4-x^2-y$$

Then, as z is positive, y is upper bounded by $$y=4-x^2$$
Finally, as y is also positive, it has to be upper bounded by $$x=2$$.

Is that reasoning correct for the boundaries?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's correct